# Is this way using a Custom Field to change Add To Card Text in WooCommerce good?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I want to be able to display a specific Add To Card Text for each single product, if set.

There are some plugins out there, but they "just" cover Add To Card Text for categories or product types. That's why I tried this way using a Custom Field.

So I wrote this code directly in a template file. This code works, but is it good, safe, at the right place?

```
// file: /woocommerce-templates/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php
<button "..." >
    <?php
        $text = get_post_meta($product->get_id(), 'add_to_cart_text', true);
    if ($text) {
        echo esc_html($text);
    } else {
        echo esc_html($product->single_add_to_cart_text()); // this line is default
    }
    ?>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this instead:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_button_text', 20, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart_button_text( $button_text, $product ) {
    $custom_button_text = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'add_to_cart_text', true );

    // If there is custom text set for this product, then display it instead of the default text.
    if ( ! empty( $custom_button_text ) ) {
        $button_text = __( $custom_button_text, 'text-domain' );
    }

    return $button_text;
}
```

Paste it in your functions.php

Comment: What's the value about working so much with filters? I personally getting overwhelmed by all those filters Woo offers, so I undertstand it better working in templates. But I guess there is a reason for filters?!

Comment: That's how plugins in Wordpress function. Most of the good ones (WooCommerce for example) have alot of filters and actions to help you change them if needed. And also the code looks much better if you have all of these in a single file.